# Cannot open the same Jquery UI dialog using another DIV tag

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, file-io, dialog

I've been trying to find a solution to allow me to open the same dialog box when a user doesn't have access to a particular site. I am only able to open the first DIV I assigned the ID to.

You can view a live example of the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/216/

Only the first "open" button works but the second one doesn't.

Example of HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="#open" id="open">Open dialog</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <a href="#open" id="open">Open dialog</a>
</div>

<div id="ok-dialog">
    <p>It's Ok!</p>
</div>
```

The function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#open').click (function() {
        $('#ok-dialog').dialog ({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Ok!'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's are supposed to be unique, used only for one element. jQuery will only select the first element with the given ID. Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! I switched id to class and that solved the problem.